# Which pins in ESP-12F are SDA SCL Pins

Tags: esp8266

I would like to use ESP-12F using I2C, however the official documentation is not clear about SCL / SDA pins on the chip. I would like to know which pins should be used for SDA / SCL on the chip. BTW the firmware is Tasmota.

Comment: By the way, I know I have already given an answer, but when you ask a question stating that documentation does not have the information, it is a good idea to include a link to said documentation

Answer (score 3):

All I did was Google the ESP-12F and the first result was [THIS](https://www.elecrow.com/download/ESP-12F.pdf). On page 14 it tells you the I2C pins needed.

Go up to page 8/9 for the pinout description.

Answer (score 1):

The Tasmota firmware uses the esp8266 Arduino core. The Wire library in esp8266 Arduino uses software I2C. It can use any pair of suitable io pins. Default pins for most [esp8266 variants](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/variants) are SDA 4 and SCL 5.